# "whether or not they're still applicable" vs. "whether they're still applicable or not"

Tags: word-order, whether-if

> The present study has been designed to examine whether or not traditional approaches are still applicable.

Is the *or not* used in the sentence correct at that place or it should be placed in the end? To my ears *whether or not* sounds like specifying a action which will/will not happen regardless of given condition e.g. *Whether or not it rains, I'm giving a party tomorrow.* Going by this sense *or not* makes more sense in the end than with *whether* in the sentence asked in question.

Comment: *whether or not* is used so often that I wouldn't split it up needlessly. It also clearly sets up the perceived decision regarding what follows.

Answer (score 1):

Being a non-native speaker, I was asked by my client (a native speaker) to use 'whether or not' instead of 'whether .... or not.' She specifically said that though both of them mean the same, it's about 'style.'

And *no,* there is no more or less sense in placing it at the end of the sentence but definitely we'll sound non-native.

Comment: I'm also a non native speaker and I would leave it out completely for brevity.

Comment: You won't sound non-native at all if you put it at the end, and that advice sounds completely arbitrary. The best thing you can do to that sentence is to nix the superfluous *or not*.